# View and display the pdf file in application without saving it in the mobile as file

Tags: android

I have this url [pdf book](http://c618227.r27.cf3.rackcdn.com/2142.pdf)

I want to download or display it in my application but without store or download the file in the mobile, the idea is to let the user display the pdf book and browser it from my application  but without saving the book as pdf file to his mobile.
I tried the Google docs view and it worked but it has a link to download(save) the file to the mobile, so user can keep the file in his mobile.
I looked for customize Download Manager in android or any good and simple tutorial but I got nothing.
I heard about something called download the pdf file as binary file so the user can't open it out side the application then display it in the application, but I couldn't know how to code it.
Please give me a hint and help me.

Comment: You want to download the PDF file?

Comment: Yah I want to download the PDF file but I want the user display it from my application not from any PDF reader was downloaded in his/her mobile like Adobe PDF reader....!!? the idea is I don't want the user gives the files or shares it with any another mobile(just display the file in his mobile) so if I download as pdf file he can share it or give it to anyone...!!

Answer (score 0):

You can use [internal storage](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/data/data-storage.html#filesInternal). But if the user roots his phone, he will be able to get your file.

So, you can encrypt your file. And decrypt it into memory (RAM) when the user wants to read the file. You can easily convert your PDF to HTML, and use [WebView](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/webkit/WebView.html) to display it. You can try googling for encrypting/ decrypting in Java.